# How to implement unique sessions for each user on my flask webapp deployed using heroku

Tags: python, flask, session, heroku, web-applications

I have recently deployed my first webapp using heroku

The website is like a notetaking app where i type a note in the box and click submit. Then it shows up. ina table that consists of other notes that I've added

The problem is when I add a note, it also shows up on my girlfriends computer far away from me. And when she adds up a note, it also shows up on my PC.

I have three theories which might have caused it:

1.) I didn't use any databases and only used lists as a way to store the info.

2.) I didn't implement something on flask

3.) It's a problem when using free heroku

Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: "only used lists as a way to store the info"—that's definitely not going to work. Presumably these are global variables?

Answer (score -1):

Use flask session to create sessions for users.

```
from flask import session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
```

you can read more on flask documentation.